# ASCII Conversion Tool Help VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make something along the lines of the Branah Unicode Converter to decode lines like this for instance: [99,97,108,108,32,99]. http://www.branah.com/unicode-converter. I found this. I'm guessing the form has a textbox and 2 buttons. One is using Asc to get the textbox's ASCII code and the other using Chr to convert the ASCII code in the textbox into a character.

So, last time I posted this, it got closed because it wasn't "a real question". Let me be blunt. I haven NO idea how to get this working. Labeling of things is very confusing. What do I declare Text1, Text2, Text3 and Label 6 as because it's giving me the error that they're not declared? I'm also getting an error that TextBox1 cannot be converted to an integer from this line: Text2 = Text2 + Chr(TextBox1). How do I fix that? Am I not importing something that I should be?

```
     Private Sub EncodeButton_Click()

     'Code the character
     TextBox1 = Asc(Text1)
     'clears text box
     Text1 = ""
     ' adds the coded character to the textbox (Textbox1)
     LABEL6 = LABEL6 + "," + TextBox1
     ' set focus to textbox
     Text1.SetFocus
     'decodes the coded character
     Text2 = Text2 + Chr(TextBox1)
   End Sub

      Private Sub DecodeButton_Click()

      'this part decodes the coded number
      TextBox1 = Text3
      Text3 = ""
      LABEL6 = LABEL6 + "," + TextBox1
      Text2 = Text2 + Chr(TextBox1)
      Text3.SetFocus
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to make this code work in VB.NET:

- Create a new Windows Forms project.
- In the project there is a form, open it and create the following items:

  - Three TextBoxes, named Text1, Text2, Text3
  - Two Buttons, named EncodeButton and DecodeButton
  - A Label named Label6
- Right click the form in solution explorer and select "View Code".
- Paste the following code into the code window:

  ```
  Public Class Form1

  Private Sub EncodeButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles EncodeButton.Click
      Dim sTextBox1 As String
      sTextBox1 = Asc(Text1.Text)
      Text1.Text = ""
      Label6.Text = Label6.Text & "," & sTextBox1
      Text1.Focus()
      Text2.Text = Text2.Text + Chr(sTextBox1)
  End Sub

  Private Sub DecodeButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DecodeButton.Click
      Dim sTextBox1 As Integer

      sTextBox1 = Val(Text3.Text)
      Text3.Text = ""
      Label6.Text = Label6.Text & "," & sTextBox1
      Text2.Text = Text2.Text & Chr(sTextBox1)
      Text3.Focus()
  End Sub

  End Class
  ```
- Run the project.
- Type a single letter into Text1 and click EncodeButton
- Type a number into Text3 (try one of the numbers that appeared in Label6 first) and click DecodeButton

This should accomplish everything the sample you pasted was designed to accomplish. If you have difficulty with any of these steps, I suggest looking up a good Windows Forms tutorial online.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just gonna do more tutorials I guess. I went through one for about a good solid week but I've been having a lot of Doctors Appointments lately. Now I'm just going to research of how to handle more than one character.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is probably that you need to understand that controls like TextBoxes have properties and methods.

So, to GET the value from a TextBox called Text1 and SET it to a TextBox called TextBox1 you'd do this:

```
 TextBox1.Text = Asc(Text1.Text)
```

If you type in the name of a control and hit the fullstop (".") character afterwards, the intellisense will give you a very helpful list of propertyies and methods you can use.

If you've copied this code from somewhere else, you may also need to create a Form, and drag/drop some TextBox controls onto it and give then names to match your code.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. I don't know if LABEL6 is an actual label. The original code actually had Label3 as the TextBox so it just made things even more confusing. I also changed the button names. But like I said, I'm still a bit confused on what I'm supposed to declare 'Text1' as for instance.

Comment: I think the sample code being worked from was written for VB6, where specifying the properties of TextBoxes and Labels was actually optional and this syntax actually inferred the Text property. To change the value of the object variable, you'd have to do `Set Text1 = something`

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that to me as well.

Comment: @basedwotonsoup if you're confused and have the code in front of you, you can appreciate that nobody else on the planet will be less confused having even less information than you do.

Comment: Sounds reassuring. Have any ideas on what I should or could do?